# Javascript task with an array and variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, var

For example I have an array in javascript:

```
var arr = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3'];
```

and I want to write every value of an array into one variable. 
So this variable should contain something like this:

```
var numbers;
console.log(numbers); // number1, number2, number
```

Comment: `var numbers = arr.join(', ')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join). It accepts a delimiter string as its argument:

```js
var arr = ['number1', 'number2', 'number3'];
var numbers = arr.join(', ');
console.log(numbers);
```